# Maximum cut variation

Tags: graph-theory, graph-cut

Given an undirected graph $G=(V,E)$, the max-cut problem asks for the partition $S_1,S_2\subset V$ , s.t., the number of edges going from $S_1$ to $S_2$ are maximized.

Is it possible to maximize the sum of all edges between $S_1$ and $S_2$ at the same time we minimize the sum of internal edges in $S_1$ partition?

Comment: The question is unclear to me.

Comment: Apparently, the problem is to find a subset $S$ of the set of vertices of graph $G$ such that the number of edges between $S$ and the complementary subset is maximal (that is, we deal with maximal cut) and the number of edges in $S$ is as small as possible. But this is what the example illustrates is not clear.

Comment: kabenyuk, your interpretation is correct, I will remove the figure to avoid misinterpretations.